# Linear View in ScrollView with Array Adapter growing up instead of down on new items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an Java Android project I am working on wherein I have a LinearLayout that is managed by an array adapter.
My issue is when I add a new item to the array adapter and update the view the List of items is growing upwards instead of down as is visible in the images below.

Why is this now growing down? and how can i make it do so?
Code follows pics
[image]

[image]

Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >

    <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/clockMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clockMain"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/annie_use_your_telescope"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateMsg"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/taskList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"

        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addNewTask"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_new_task"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.95"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Task List

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskDesc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="testing task"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is bull shit"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/taskTime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some more bullish"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

inflator

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_list, null);
        TextView taskDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.taskDesc);
        TextView taskDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.taskDate);
        TextView taskTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.taskTime);

        taskDesc.setText(tasks.get(i).description);
        taskDate.setText(tasks.get(i).taskDate.toString());
        taskTime.setText(tasks.get(i).taskTime.toString());

        return view;
    }
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TaskAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<Task> tasks;

    public TaskAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.tasks = new ArrayList<>(tasks);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tasks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_list, null);
        TextView taskDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.taskDesc);
        TextView taskDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.taskDate);
        TextView taskTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.taskTime);

        taskDesc.setText(tasks.get(i).description);
        taskDate.setText(tasks.get(i).taskDate.toString());
        taskTime.setText(tasks.get(i).taskTime.toString());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the array adapter you are using(how you are inserting data in arrayadapter) and where you are passing the array to listview.

Comment: any thoughts...?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't able to response in last few days.
Your problem is layout right?
not the logic of adapter and any other things.
like the margin is getting lesser between `Whats next` and list right?